# Real time sine wave plotting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just starting python a few weeks ago and I started off with printing command, plotting and loops. And now Im trying to combine all these into sine wave function. I looked up here and there and I finally came across codes that let me plot real time sine wave. Only one problem though, the x-axis is static and does not update along with the graph. I'd like to make it not bound to any timeframe so it goes on forever. Here's the code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from collections import deque 
import math

i=0

def sin_gen():
    t=0
    while True:
    val = math.sin(0.1*t)
    yield val
    t+=1
    time.sleep(0.1)

a1 = deque([0]*100)

d=sin_gen()

line, = plt.plot(a1)
plt.ion()
plt.ylim([-1,1])
plt.show()

while True:
    a1.appendleft(next(d))
    datatoplot = a1.pop()
    line.set_ydata(a1)
    plt.draw()
    print (a1[0])
    i += 1
    time.sleep(0.1)
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

Really appreciate constructive comments! Thanks for help!

Comment: I don't understand what behaviour you want. I try your code and it goes forever. Do you want the x values to be updated with time?